# Stein Variational Gradient Descent in Particle Filter

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to implement the Stein Particle Filter described in this paper. (https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.04213)

I don't understand how to get the prediction probabilities in equation (12). The mathematical expression seems to takes the mean of all samples? Does that make sense?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is an empirical version of $$\mathbb E[p(x_t|X_{t-1},u_t)|z_{1:t-1},u_{1:t-1}]$$

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
There are people using screen-readers, and just an image of text cant be used by them!